# Give a sequence such that: $\forall \epsilon >0 $ $\exists N \in \Bbb N$ such that if $N \le n \le N+2$ then $|X_n - L| \ge \epsilon $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, cauchy-sequences

I have to solve a lot of excercises like these but I am not sure of my answers and in some cases I do not what to do.

Give a sequence $X_n$  and a number L such that:

1) $\forall \epsilon >0  $ and  $\forall N   \in  \Bbb N$ such that if $n \ge N$ then $|X_n - L| < \epsilon $

I did: $a_n=1$ then $|a_n-1|=0<\epsilon$

2)$\forall \epsilon >0  $  $\exists N   \in  \Bbb N$ such that if $n \le N$ then $|X_n - L| < \epsilon $

I did the same: $a_n=0$ then $|a_n-0|=0<\epsilon$

3)$\forall \epsilon >0  $   $\exists  N   \in  \Bbb N$ such that if $N \le n \le N+2$ then $|X_n - L| \ge \epsilon $

I do not have an idea at all.

4)$\exists \epsilon >0  $ such that $\forall N   \in  \Bbb N$ if $ n \ge N$ then $|X_n - L| \ge \epsilon $

In this case I think it is not possible give a sequence like this because if this happens then $a_n$ is divergent.

5)$\exists \epsilon >0  $   $\exists  N   \in  \Bbb N$ such that if $n \neq N $ then $|X_n - L| = \epsilon $

6) $\forall \epsilon >0  $   $\exists N   \in  \Bbb N$ such that if $n \ge L$ then $|\epsilon - N| < X_n $

7)$\exists \epsilon >0  $   $\exists  N   \in  \Bbb N$ such that if $n \ge N $ then $|X_n - L| \ge n\epsilon $

8)$\forall \epsilon >0  $   $\exists  N   \in  \Bbb N$ such that if $n \ge \epsilon $ then $|X_n - L| \ge N $

Any ideas or hint?

Comment: Case 1:  Did you mean $a_n = L$?

Comment: Case 1:  $|a_n - L| = |1 - L|$ which will not be less than every epsilon unless L = 1.  So that isn't right.

Case 2:  $|a_n - L| = |0 - L = |L|$ which will not be less than every epsilon unless L = 0.  So that isn't right.

But both could be easily made right is $a_n = L$ for all n.  That will work in *both* cases.

Comment: Case 3:  You have to define N in terms of epsilon.  |$a_{N} - L$| >= epsilon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case 1 and 2:  You want $|a_n - L| < \epsilon$.  You showed $|an - 1| < \epsilon$ in case 1 and $|an - 0| < \epsilon$ in case 2 which wasn't asked for.

In both cases let $a_n = L$ and you're good.

Case 3.  You need to define N in terms of epsilon.  As you want things to get *bigger* then epsilon you want it to diverge.  Any divergent sequence will work.  As you will want to subtract L, I suggest $a_n = n + L$.  Then for any $\epsilon > 0$, if $N \ge \epsilon$ then for $N \le n \le N+2$,  $|a_n - L| = |n + L -L| =n >= N \ge \epsilon$.

Weird but works.

Case 4: It does have to be divergent.  But the exercise never said divergence wasn't allowed.   But this doesn't actually need to be divergent as $\epsilon$ is not arbitrary in this case.  Let epsilon be ... whatever you like.  $\epsilon = 27$, say.  Then you need to find a sequence, and an N such that if n $\ge$ N then $|a_n - L|$ $\ge$ 27.  Such an N could be anything arbitrary so N = 3.  Then {$a_n$} = {97, -2, 27+ L, 28 + L, -L - 29, 500 + L, 27 + L, 31 + L......} will do.  Or something less absurd.

Okay, this exercise is *weird*!  But I sort of like it.  It forces you to think about exactly what is being asked and literally what does it mean.  But I don't like that it plays on expectations and completely thwarts them.  Usually we use these N, epsilon to show convergence with the *expectation* that the epsilon is an arbitrarily small value with we try to squeeze values of the sequence between, and N is a corresponding large value for which index value or terms will be squeezed.  In this exercise, this values are nothing at all of the kind.

Case 5:  Okay, *some* (not all) epsilon, a value of N and for all n $\ne$ N, $|a_n -L| = \epsilon$.  So epsilon is a constant. $a_n - L = \pm \epsilon$ for all n $\ne$ N another constant.  Okay... let epsilon be 1.  N = 35.  $a_n$ = L + 1 for all n $\ne$ to 35. $a_{35} = \frac{-5,726}{\pi}$.

... and so on....